# C++17 / C++1z parallel usage of std::for_each

Tags: c++, c++17

I want to use C++17 parallel capabilities to divide every element of a `std::vector` by some constant and store the result in another `std::vector` of same length and (!!) order.

E.g.

```
{6,9,12} / 3 = {2,3,4}
```

I have a not compiling example

```
#include <execution>
#include <algorithm>

template <typename T>
std::vector<T> & divide(std::vector<T> const & in)
{
  std::vector<T> out(in.size(), 0);

  float const divisor = 3;

  std::for_each
  ( std::execution::par_unseq
  , in.begin()
  , in.end()
  , /* divide each element by divisor and put result in out */ );

  return out;
}
```

How can I get this running, lockless and threadsafe?

Comment: `vector` is not a threadsafe container to begin with, so you can't even use it as is without locking.

Comment: also post the relevant compiler error, please

Comment: `vector` is not threadsafe but for sure, you can use it lockless if every thread has it's range of elements to alter.
There are no compiler errors as `std::for_each` is obviously in totally wrong state.

Comment: `std::for_each` won't do this. Use `std::transform`.

Comment: First get it working single threaded...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

something like this:

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <execution>

template <typename T>
std::vector<T> divide(std::vector<T> result)
{
    // ^^ take a copy of the argument here - will often be elided anyway 

    float const divisor = 3;

    // the following loop mutates distinct objects within the vector and
    // invalidates no iterators. c++ guarantees that each object is distinct
    // and that neighbouring objects may be updated by different threads
    // at the same time without a mutex.
    std::for_each(
        std::execution::par, 
        std::begin(result), 
        std::end(result), 
        [divisor](T& val) {  // copies are safer, and the resulting code will be as quick.
            // modifies value in place
            val /= divisor;
        });

    // implicit fence here. Safe to manipulate the vector as a whole.
    // from here on

  // return by value. Allows RVO.
  return result;
}
```

Comment: Note that the single threaded O(n) vector copy will probably dominate your latency in practice.  Avoiding that somehow may be worthwhile.

Comment: @Yakk I'm pretty sure that for this trivial transformation, vectorisation will always beat parallelisation in any case, but at least now the code compiles :)

Answer (score 3):

You want `std::transform` for this, not `std::for_each`. Transofrm takes input and output iterators.

The good thing about `std::transform` is that it is trivial to distribute to multiple CPU cores, if needed. So:

```
#include <execution>
#include <algorithm>

template <typename T>
std::vector<T> & divide(std::vector<T> const & in)
{
  std::vector<T> out(in.size(), 0);

  float const divisor = 3;

  std::transform
  ( std::execution::par_unseq
    in.begin(),
    in.end(),
    out.begin(),
    out.end(),
        [divisor](float val) {
            // modifies value in place
            return val / divisor;
        });

  return out;
}
```

Sidenote: if you are into speed, either enable `-ffast-math` or multiply with `(1 / divisor)`